# Getting an error trying to Route a page (Rails Server)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm attempting to try Routing for the first time. I'm following along with a book from Learn-rails.com. Author says to delete what is in **config/routes.rb** and replace it with: `

```
LearnRails::Aplication.routes.draw do 
  root to: redirect('/about.html') 
end
```

After I saved the file, and then refresh localhost:3000 I get this NameError page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zMfdT.jpg

It says:

> Tip: add gem "binding_of_caller" to your Gemfile to enable the REPL
>   and local/instance variable inspection.

Which I did add, and did "`bundle install`". Then I tried to restart rails server in a new window, and now that won't work. If I remove what the Author said to add to the routes.rb file. Everything is fine. Does anyone have any ideas on what is going on? Thanks!

Comment: LearnRails::Aplication, it's Application.Check just the spelling.may be a typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The screenshot clearly specifies, missing 'p' in `LearnRails::Aplication` is creating the issue. Just replace and it should work

Comment: Ugh! Sorry, guys! That's what I get for attempting this on no sleep.

Answer (score 1):

There are some exception and the better_error is unable to show the error.
Add following line into gem file.

```
gem 'binding_of_caller', :platforms=>[:mri_19, :mri_20, :rbx]
```

Run 'bundle install'
Then check for the exception and post it here, I will try to help with that.